# How to skip some urls from X-frame-options for cross origin nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location, x-frame-options

I have added x-frame-options in Nginx sites-available file.
"add_header X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN
Now I want to skip this header for some URLs.
Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it using [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive (should be placed at `http` context **outside** the `server` block):

```
map $uri $frame_options {
    /some/uri     '';
    /another/uri  '';
    ...
    default       SAMEORIGIN;
}
```

If you are familiar with regex expressions, you can use them within the `map` block using `~` modifier, e.g. `~^/(some|another)/uri$ '';`

Then use the `add_header` directive in your `server` block this way:

```
add_header  X-Frame-Options $frame_options;
```

If the `$frame_options` variable will have an empty value, nginx won't add an empty `X-Frame-Options` header to the response, instead it won't add that header at all.